# Decent tool/library for C++ to handle XML?

Tags: c++, xml

I need to do some XML-related job (parsing, comparison etc). Is there any C++ library for this that you know works good ? Preferrably for Win XP. Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE : I also tried XML parser from http://www.applied-mathematics.net/tools/xmlParser.html, which worked fine and I had no problems regarding Unicode support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PugiXml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/) will do it.

Answer (score 5):

Tiny XML! Good library, ugly homepage: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/

Answer (score 2):

I use libxml2: http://www.xmlsoft.org

Answer (score 1):

I used wxWidgets which has wxXmlDocument class that does a lot of hard work for you. It uses Expat internally, but handles all the charset conversions on its own. This is if you want a DOM based parser.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxxmldocument.html

You might also want to look at Xerces, esp. if you want a SAX parser:

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try Xerces, Pugixml and Mini-XML.

Answer (score 0):

The [xmlwrapp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlwrapp/) library is C++ wrapper around libxml2 that is quite usable and has the most C++-ish API from the alternatives I tried.